# git-flow hotfixes with semantic versioning

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow, git-tag

Following Jeff's tutorial at http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/, I initialised git flow with the standard settings:

```
[~/tmp/test]
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/nrm/tmp/test/.git/

[~/tmp/test (master)]
$ git flow init
No branches exist yet. Base branches must be created now.
Branch name for production releases: [master]
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop]

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [feature/]
Release branches? [release/]
Hotfix branches? [hotfix/]
Support branches? [support/]
Version tag prefix? []

[~/tmp/test (develop)]
$
```

I follow the tutorial up to the section "Hotfixing production code". There the hotfix branch is named "assets":

```
$ git flow hotfix start assets
Switched to a new branch 'hotfix/assets'

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'hotfix/assets' was created, based on 'master'
- You are now on branch 'hotfix/assets'

Follow-up actions:
- Bump the version number now!
- Start committing your hot fixes
- When done, run:

     git flow hotfix finish 'assets'
```

BUT, when the hotfix branch is closed the tutorial states `The hotfix was tagged '0.1.1'`. How come? I'm using `git-flow: stable 0.4.1`.

When I close the hotfix by `git flow hotfix finish 'assets'`, then the tag is equal to the hotfix branch name:

```
$ git flow hotfix finish assets
                         ^^^^^^
Switched to branch 'master'
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 assets.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 assets.txt
Switched to branch 'develop'
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 assets.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 assets.txt
Deleted branch hotfix/assets (was 08edb94).    

Summary of actions:
- Latest objects have been fetched from 'origin'
- Hotfix branch has been merged into 'master'
- The hotfix was tagged 'assets'
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
- Hotfix branch has been back-merged into 'develop'
- Hotfix branch 'hotfix/assets' has been deleted
```

Actually, I want to have both. Name a hotfix branch with some string (like "assets" in the example) independently from the tag name. Something like

```
$ git flow hotfix finish assets --with-tag 1.0.1
```

resulting in

```
$ git flow hotfix finish assets --with-tag 1.0.1

Switched to branch 'master'
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 assets.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 assets.txt
Switched to branch 'develop'
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 assets.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 assets.txt
Deleted branch hotfix/assets (was 08edb94).
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Summary of actions:
- Latest objects have been fetched from 'origin'
- Hotfix branch has been merged into 'master'
- The hotfix was tagged '1.0.1'
                         ^^^^^
- Hotfix branch has been back-merged into 'develop'
- Hotfix branch 'hotfix/assets' has been deleted
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any suggestions?